# Laravel Passport change User Model

Tags: laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel Passport 5.7.
I want to use own model to authenticate user.
When I change custom User into mine Tenancy it always says 'unarhorized'.

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        ...
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'tenants',
        ],
        ...
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'tenants' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Tenancy::class,
        ],

    ],
```

login controller

```
if(!auth('api')->check($credentials)){
             return 'unarhorized';
         }

        return auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```

when I try

```
if(!auth('api')->attempt($credentials))
```

I get

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.
```

Where could be problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you seletect  `'driver' => 'passport',`

then you cannot `attempt()`

so you need to

use

```php
if(!auth()->attempt($credentials))
    return  auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```

then protect by `api` middleare

then you can check

```php
f(!auth('api')->check($credentials)){
    return 'unarhorized';
}
```